# Passing new elements to an array within class and returning its values

Tags: php, arrays, function, class, variables

```
class Item 
{
private $_SomeArray = array();
private $elementOfanArray;

function __construct()
{
    $this->_SomeArray[0]="default message";
    $this->elementOfanArray=0;    //I am trying to assign empty value to an var
}

public function getArray()
{
    return $this->SomeArray;  //function returning whole array
}
public function setArray(elementOfanArray)  //function for adding new element to an array and checking if not empty
{
if(!elementOfanArray)
    {

    }
else
    {
        array_push($_SomeArray, elementOfanArray);

        $elementOfanArray = 0; //I am trying to assign value after addding element to an array
    }
}


function __destruct(){
    $this->_SomeArray;
    $this->elementOfanArray;
}
}
```

This is my code but now i am wondering if using "array_push" is right choice as it will get called around 20 times.
The amount of function calls is not constant so if there will be less values.. i would like to remove them from the array or just immediately dump them.

Another question i got is how should i get my elements out of this class, is there a way of getting whole array with values outside of this class?

Is it even right what i wrote?

Comment: if you call variables from your class inside that class or functions, you need to use `$this->`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question about using `array_push`: It doesn't really matter how many times you're using it, it does the job of adding an item to the array. So use it!

You could also use this syntax `$array[] = 'value'` which also does the same thing.

A few notes:

1) Variable names in php must begin with a `$`. There are several places in your code that doesn't have them such as:

```
public function setArray(elementOfanArray)
```

and

```
if (!elementOfanArray) {
```

2) There is a naming inconsistency between the name used in your function `SomeArray` and the name in your constructor `_SomeArray`.

3) Since `_SomeArray` is a property of the class, you need to access it using `$this->_SomeArray` in your setArray function:

```
array_push($this->_SomeArray, $elementOfanArray);
```

4) There's really no value in using destructor just to clear out local variables, they will be unset when the object is destroyed.  Usually, you would use the destructor to do things like closing connections, saving state, etc.
Currently, it looks like you would use your class something like this:

```
$myItem = new Item();

$myItem->setArray('Array Item #1');
$myItem->setArray('Array Item #2');
$myItem->setArray('Array Item #3');

$array = $myItem->getArray();

var_dump($array);
// returns:
//
// array(4) {
//     [0]=>
//   string(15) "default message"
//     [1]=>
//   string(13) "Array Item #1"
//     [2]=>
//   string(13) "Array Item #2"
//     [3]=>
//   string(13) "Array Item #3"
// }
```

5) I'm not sure what your intention was for the class property `elementOfanArry`:

```
$this->elementOfanArray = 0;    //I am trying to assign empty value to an var
```

If you were thinking that you need it because the `setArray()` method accepts a parameter, this is not the case.

So all in all, to simply address the title of your post "Passing new elements to an array within class and returning its values", the code could look like this:

```
class Item
{
    private $_SomeArray = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->_SomeArray[0] = "default message";
    }

    public function getArray()
    {
        return $this->_SomeArray;  //function returning whole array
    }

    public function setArray($elementOfanArray)  //function for adding new element to an array and checking if not empty
    {
        if (!$elementOfanArray) {

        } else {
            array_push($this->_SomeArray, $elementOfanArray);
            // or use:
            // $this->_SomeArray[] = $elementOfanArray;
        }
    }
}


$myItem = new Item();

$myItem->setArray('Array Item #1');
$myItem->setArray('Array Item #2');
$myItem->setArray('Array Item #3');

$array = $myItem->getArray();
```

Comment: Very well put answer to my question with every aspect i mentioned.
Thank you for your input :).

Comment: My intention of setting elementOfanArray to 0 was in case of calling the function with empty value to not make array bigger. There is a chance that i can not even call function without passing variable to it, so it could be useless.

Comment: That's not a bad thought, but in your current code, you aren't using that variable at all anywhere.  I think you may have been confusing it with parameter in  your `setArray()` method that has the same name.

Comment: I don't see elementOfanArray being declared in your code. Is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: This is correct. You do not need to declare it outside of the function. I guess you could say it is declared when you list is as a parameter in your function declaration. `public function setArray($elementOfanArray)`